# TensorFlow get accuracy of a single prediction

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression, mnist

I implemented a logistic regression model using TensorFlow and the `mnist` dataset. I figure out how to get the total accuracy of the learning algorithm using the following code...

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

This works fine and print an accuracy of 91%. Now I am restoring the model and passing a single image into the model to make a prediction. I pass a picture of a number 7, `mnist.test.images[0]`, and it predicts it correctly -> `[7]`...

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    x_in = np.expand_dims(mnist.test.images[0], axis=0)
    classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(pred, 1), feed_dict={x:x_in})
    print(classification)
```

Now I want to get the accuracy of this prediction in relation to the model but I'm not sure how to proceed, I tried the following which obviously does not work...

```
 accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(classification, tf.float32))
 print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The output of this is `Accuracy: 7.0`

If a straightforward answer is not possible, I would appreciate some steps needed in order to achieve what I want.

Comment: Sorry I do not get really what you want to do. What do you mean by "accuracy of this prediction in relation to the model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accuracy of a single prediction does not make a lot of sense.

You will get either 0% or 100%.

But you can still use the accuracy operation that you create in your graph:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    x_in = np.expand_dims(mnist.test.images[0], axis=0)
    y_in = np.expand_dims(mnist.test.labels[0], axis=0)
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: x_in , y: y_in}))
```